# TinyMCE javascript errors

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

i Have downloaded TinyMCE and running examples. When i run any example and click on html button of TinyMCE GUI i am getting js errors

`Permission denied for <file://> to get property Window.tinymce from <file://>.`

  and

`this.params is undefined`

Check these errors in Firefox while opening firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers can be overly strict when loading files directly from the file system.  Try putting the examples on a web server and you'll probably find they work correctly.

Regards,

Adrian Sutton
http://tinymce.ephox.com